# No qualifying bean of type 'springfox.documentation.schema.property.ModelPropertiesProvider' after obfuscation with proguard

Tags: proguard, obfuscation, swagger-2.0

My Swagger config works fine normally, but when I use proguard to obfuscate the code, I get the error

```
No qualifying bean of type 'springfox.documentation.schema.property.ModelPropertiesProvider'
```

If I comment **@Configuration**, the spring boot project starts but swagger documentation doesn't work and I get another error

```
Unable to infer base url. This is common when using dynamic servlet registration or when the API is behind an API Gateway. The base url is the root of where all the swagger resources are served
```

Here is my swagger config class

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.Contact;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@Profile("swagger")
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("Spring REST TSU service with Swagger")
            .description("Spring REST TSU service with Swagger")
            .termsOfServiceUrl("...")
            .contact(new Contact("Test name", "", "test@asdf.com"))
            .version("1.0")
            .build();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved for me! Override the method buildDefaultBeanName in class AnnotationBeanNameGenerator. eg.

```
@ServletComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebApplication {

public static void run() {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(WebApplication.class)
            .beanNameGenerator(new ProGuardBeanNameGenerator()).run();
}

static class ProGuardBeanNameGenerator extends AnnotationBeanNameGenerator {
    @Override
    protected String buildDefaultBeanName(BeanDefinition definition) {
        return definition.getBeanClassName();
    }
}
```

}